# html form javascript gets ignored

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am having difficulties to implement JavaScript into my html form.
I am using alot of PHP throughout. The code I am about to post, is included in a seperate page the user accesses. It is a php page.

The form currently does not include action=, which would submit it to formposts.php. I took it out to see if my JavaScript just got ignored and the form was sent before checkign JavaScript. But even without action, my form does not respond to the JavaScript.

I have used simple forms of JS, just to check if it works, before getting down to details. I really need some help pls on how to make this work, I dont know where the problem is !!

I have included the script call when opening the form, and when closing. onsubmit // onclick I have also tried including a label to show text. The JS is at the end off the code. You can ignore some of the text / script. I guess the opening of the form, first three input types, the closing of the form and JS is included. I have taken some out, as it is a long form.

```
    <p><?php echo $session->getText("profileInfo",$language); ?></p>

<table width="530" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" width="40%"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()" name="registration">
                                <img src="<?php echo $userDetails['picUrl']; ?>" border="none"> ;</th>
    <th scope="col" width="60%"><h3><?php echo $session->getText("profileMenuPersonal",$language); ?></h3></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><h4><?php echo $session->getText("regPic",$language); ?></h4></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="uploaded" id="uploaded" onblur="checkType()"  /> <label id="picMSG"></label> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><h4><?php echo $session->getText("regFname",$language); ?></h4></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $userDetails['firstName']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><h4><?php echo $session->getText("regLname",$language); ?></h4></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $userDetails['lastName']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr>   <!--  I have taken some code out for readability of this post -->
    <td><input type="hidden" id="reqtype" name="reqtype" value="personalDetails"  />
        <input type="hidden" id="realUserId" name="realUserId" value="<?php echo $realUserId; ?>" /></td>            
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update / save" class="button" onclick="return checkForm()" />
        </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkForm()
    {
        var picture = document.getElementById('uploaded').value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
        var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
        var postCode = document.getElementById('postCode').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        //      files types that r not allowed
        //      And are considered harming - 
        //      someone purposfully trying to harm the system
        var str1 = ".php"; 
        var str2 = ".js";
        var str3 = ".html"; 
        if(!document.registration.firstName.value)
        {
            alert('please enter name');
            return false;
        }
        if(picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str2) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str3) != -1)
        { 
            alert("You have tried to upload content that may harm our system. The admin has been contacted and your account flagged. You may be deleted."); 
            return false;
        }
        // allowed file types
        var str1 = ".jpeg"; 
        var str2 = ".gif";
        var str3 = ".png";
        if(picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 )
        {
            return true;
        }else{
                alert("We only allow jpeg, gif and png files to be uploaded."); 
                return false;
        }

    }
    function checkType()
    {
        var picture = document.getElementById('uploaded').value;
        var element = document.getElementById('picMSG').value
        //      files types that r not allowed
        //      And are considered harming - 
        //      someone purposfully trying to harm the system
        var str1 = ".php"; 
        var str2 = ".js";
        var str3 = ".html"; 
        if(picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str2) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str3) != -1)
        { 
            element.innerHTML = "invalid type";
            element.style.color = "red";
        }
        // allowed file types
        var str1 = ".jpeg"; 
        var str2 = ".gif";
        var str3 = ".png";
        if(picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 || picture.indexOf(str1) != -1 )
        {
            return true;
        }else{

        }
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea why my "simple" JS is being ignored ??

I am new to PHP and JS. but wiould have thought this was a simple task. What am I doing worng ?

Comment: What is "SJ"?  What errors are you getting? Have you looked at an error console or attempted any debug at all?

Comment: remove return from `return checkForm()`.

Comment: [validate validate validate](http://validator.w3.org/) — Browsers do very odd things when you incorrectly mix forms and tables.

Comment: If you have a JavaScript problem, then don't show us server side code. Show us what the browser sees.

Comment: @ Quentin, What would you like to see ???? sorry, just not sure what you would like instead ? firbug output ?

Comment: stripped down teh code, started from scratch. Thanks @everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my wild guess... after i stripped your code to bits... http://jsfiddle.net/VVYR3/15/

change your submit button to:

`onclick="checkForm()"` instead of `onsubmit="return checkForm()"` (you can experiment further once you get this bit working)

and most **importantly** your script shouldn't be AFTER your form, instead place it in `<HEAD>`

Comment: I have put the script into teh head section and changed teh suggested bit. My JS still seems to be ignored. I do have to mention, that putting the script in the head section, mean putting it in diff file. As the main page is myprofile.php, in which with php i say, include (profileDetails.php); which hold this form

Comment: well, if you check my fiddle - it woks. i'm suggesting you slowly add more code to it and check it works at every stage... see my update with full code - it works http://jsfiddle.net/VVYR3/17/

Comment: great littl aid you have there. This indicates for me, that it must be a bug, in terms of teh way I structured my page and code, as teh code on its own it correct !! Thanks for you reply. I will rewrite my page, and test it again, if it works I will accept this as an answer, as it show the code its self works ! The issue must lie within page set-up, and all the php wthin it or so

Comment: it's always a good idea to see your _outputted_ code in browser (view source code), to see the page structure you suggest to browser to work with.. hope you resolve your issue..

Comment: Best was to stripp down the code, do one field at a time. Tried to much at once. Getting there now. Thanks @everyone

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to debug it for you since you removed part of the code but I tried anyway and checkForm was called on submit allright. It fails on

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

since there is no element with the id of "email" on which to find a value.

Your validation is somewhat sloppy though, what about a file called jpg.exe. It would pass as the code is now.

Have you considered not reinventing the wheel and use a tested framework instead? There are plenty of them out there, and they even have nice fancy ajax functionality. Like this: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: well I would be happy for it to throw error at me. But for me it gets ignored. Could that be the case because of how i structur the pages with PHP. When I click submit, nothing happens. It should at least show enter name or similar !? The code i have taken out r just simply all the other input fields. Thanks for your reply !!

Comment: dude u where right. It must have stopped at this, since my email fields is actually called email1 due to some css i didnt want in there. Shame I cant accept 2 answers. u where right, but elen helped em gettign there ;) thx for ur help !

Comment: Good thing you got it sorted. You might want to consider debugging with Firebug extension to Firefox for these cases. I find it easier to find where code fails that way. The other browsers has debuggers as well but I still find Firebug to be the best.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you have to do this

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update / save" class="button" onclick="checkForm()" />`

instead of

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update / save" class="button" onclick="return checkForm()" />`

---

try changing

`if(!document.registration.firstName.value)`

into
`if(firstName == "")`

and(every)

`picture.indexOf(str1) != -1`

into
`picture.search(str1) == -1`

and check whether it works or not >.>

Comment: No. That would cause the return value of the `checkForm` function to be ignored … which would defeat the object.

Comment: I have deleted the return part, still no respons of the JS at all

Comment: I dont get an error. It just gets ignored !? the thing is, I have a main php page, on which I include the page as seen above. I dont know if that causes an issue ?

Comment: then i assume(again) that it doesn't return anything. have you tried to use `alert` before the `if` conditions; checking whether the function is called or not?

Comment: @aquatorrent well, thx for this simple suggestion, I finally got an alert box ! :D sorry if i seem little dumb here, but sometimes you get to stuck with an issue and dont manage an out of the box view anymore. Plus I am under time pressure here ;)

Comment: could the proplem be that, ie with checking the name, it gets an value filled from the DB using PHP  . . . in this case -> "pls enter name".

Comment: which i obviously delete when using the form, and press submit with an emptey field !

Comment: no, still no success. Even If i take my php code out, it does not work. However, placing the alert in the beginning of the function works ! So it seems as if it does not reach teh if statements. I mean, not even the function for the firstName works !? I am assuming it has to do with my page set-up

Comment: try getting the data then :) the alert works, isn't it? then you can use it to tell you the data you got(and what are you missing there) ;)

Comment: I started stripping down the code, doing one field at a time. Thanks @everyone